# Chromedriver no MAC - Eclipse/Intellij

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, automatização

Estou com o seguinte problema:
Estou agora com MAC e não consigo mais executar minha automação.

Já fiz o download do Chrome para MAC, mas mesmo assim recebo o seguinte erro:

java.lang.IllegalStateException: The driver executable does not exist: /Users/estevaomarcos/Documents/Projetos/DBServer/\Users\chromedriver

No meu código está o seguinte:
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "\Users\chromedriver");

Alguém poderia me auxiliar?

Desde já agradeço.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fala carinha, blz? olha de cara eu falaria que o caminho do driver esta incorreto. já verificou isso? tenta colocar ele em uma pasta dentro do projeto por exemplo:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", ".//src//test//resources//chromedriver");
```

Comment: Bom dia Marcos Costa! Funcionou! Muito obrigado viu!